# What is the difference between "comparison" and "contrast" in psychological statistics?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, contrasts, psychology

What is the difference between a "comparison" and a "contrast" in psychological statistics?

For example, what is the difference between multiple comparisons and planned contrast?

Comment: The *contrasts* tag may be of interest to you:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/contrasts/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparison can be made with inferential statistics. Multiple comparisons require special adjustments to conserve the familywise error rates. Contrasts, however, refer to how regression models use matrices to represent the differences calculated in treatments of two or more levels.